# View with custom onTouchEvent handling performs very badly in ListView but performs perfectly in a LinearLayout ScrollView combo

Tags: android, listview

I have a class that extends RelativeLayout and in this class I override "onTouchEvent" and handle left/right sliding manually by using the x moved to position 3 views in my custom RelativeLayout layout by setting their "setTranslationX(float translationX)".

I have a test activity with a ScrollView that contain one single LinearLayout that then contains 200 of my custom RelativeLayout object, and it performs perfectly.

But it really has to live inside a ListView, so I have implemented a custom ArrayAdapter and return my custom RelativeLayout objects like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  final Transaction transaction = getItem(position);

  if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = new SlidingCellView(getContext());
    cellViews.add((SlidingCellView) convertView);
  }

  ((SlidingCellView) convertView).update(new SlidingCellView.SlidingCellViewResources() {
        @Override
        public String getSlidingCellName() {
            return transaction.getText();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

The problem is that when I do this I get really bad performance, even with only 100 elements in the list. When I drag/slide the SlidingCellView to the side, I get jagged movement, and I do not get that in my 200 element ScrollView/LinearLayout test.

Any ideas why this is so? Why the difference, and can I do something to fix this?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) fixes a lot of problems that ListView has when dealing with clicks and touches on views *inside* the individual views that make up the list.  In fact, you should be preferring RecyclerView for scrolling lists in almost all circumstances.

There are a lot of great tutorials out there on how to use RecyclerView.  It's too much to put here.